# In the iOS Mail app, how do I share an email, or save to Files, etc.?

Tags: ios, mail.app, pdf

In the iOS Mail app, there's no "Share" button (box with an arrow) that presents the standard share sheet with options to send via Messages/Airdrop, save to Files, open in other apps, etc. Is there any way to share the contents of an email other than forwarding, replying, or printing?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, this is the best solution:

1. Tap the button to Print the email
2. Pinch-zoom the print page preview to fill the screen
3. Now you should see what's effectively a PDF of the email, including headers and all pages, and there will be a Share button in the top bar
4. Tap the Share button to get all the standard options to share a PDF of the email

If the email has any attachments that can't be displayed inline, then it looks like the PDF that's shared will just include an icon representing the file. So these attachments would have to be opened and shared separately.

Answer (score 1):

On iPad in particular, you could drag the empty part on an email and drop it to any app that supports drag&drop feature. This will include the entire email (including senders, receivers, etc) and a url scheme link back to the email in the mail app.

Comment: Note that the app being dropped into has to support the “.eml” file type to view the content. Some only gets eml but can’t read it, e.g., Files; and some only get sthe link, e.g., Things. So far, the one that does both is DEVONthink To Go,